# Image selection region stretching to rectagle

Tags: c++, image, qt, opencv, image-processing

Currently working on one issue, which is illustrated on represented image.

[image: problem description]

On the left hand side source image is represented. I have selection region, which could be a polygon of 4 points.
On the right hand side result of image cutting is represented. As it can be seen pixels appeared in selection region were stretched to rectagle of resulting image.

I would like to know how to get such effect by using regular Qt or OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process could be performed with Qt using the following functions:

- [`QTransform::squareToQuad`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html#squareToQuad): create the transformation matrix

> Creates a transformation matrix, trans, that maps a unit square to a four-sided polygon, quad. Returns true if the transformation is constructed or false if such a transformation does not exist.

- [`QImage::transformed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#transformed-1): to transform the image with the constructed transformation matrix

> Returns a copy of the image that is transformed using the given transformation matrix and transformation mode.

- [`QImage::copy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#copy): extract the desired area

> Returns a sub-area of the image as a new image.

*Please try to read the docs and consider posting your solution when it works.*

Answer (score 0):

Method, decribed by m7913d, may to be useful.
I tried to implement it, but, unfortunately, i wasn`t able to get good results (maybe because of mistakes in coordinates specifying).

I also found similar methods in OpenCV.
And as it was more simple api to use (in my case) i wrote following code:

```
Mat src_img = imread(path.toStdString(), 1);
imshow("source", src_img);

//vectors for corners
vector<Point2f> origin;
vector<Point2f> dest;

//output image size
int w = src_img.cols;
int h = src_img.rows;

//specifing roi polygon
origin.clear();
origin.push_back(Point2f(w / 2 - 20, h / 2 - 20));  //lt
origin.push_back(Point2f(w / 2 + 20, h / 2 - 100)); //rt
origin.push_back(Point2f(w / 2 - 20, h / 2 + 20));  //lb
origin.push_back(Point2f(w / 2 + 20, h / 2 + 20));  //rb

//resut storage
Mat result(w, h, CV_8UC4);

//specifing area, where we want to place warped roi
dest.clear();
dest.push_back(Point2f(0, 0));
dest.push_back(Point2f(w / 2, 0));
dest.push_back(Point2f(0, h / 2));
dest.push_back(Point2f(w / 2, h / 2));

//creating transform matrix
Mat warpMatrix = getPerspectiveTransform(origin, dest);

//warping and getting result
warpPerspective(src_img, result, warpMatrix, Size(w / 2, h / 2));
imshow("result", result);

//create a black image and merge images into one
Mat sum(w, h, CV_8UC4, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
src_img.copyTo(sum);
result.copyTo(sum(Rect(40, 80, result.cols, result.rows)));
imshow("final", sum);
```